# Using a variable for an Jquery selector

Tags: jquery, variables, selector

I'm trying to build an image gallery that is both a vertical scroll and navigable through the use of next/prev buttons.

Each image has an ID ranging from 1-31 and basically want to use their IDs to affect scrollTop. However I'm getting an error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement. (01.html:70)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.0.js:5110)

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style01.css">
<script src="../jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="show-info">
<i>The Four Seasons </i> <BR>
May 30 - Jul 16, 2015<BR>
<BR>
Night Gallery<BR>
Los Angelos, CA<br>

<button class="prev">prev</button>/
<button class="next">next</button>

</div>


<div id="exterior-container">
<div id="project-container"
<img  id="1" src="../Projects/Images/Night/01.jpg" class="long"> <br>
<img  id="2" src="../Projects/Images/Night/02.jpg" class="long"> <br>
<img  id="3" src="../Projects/Images/Night/03.jpg" class="long"> <br>
<img  id="4" src="../Projects/Images/Night/04.jpg" class="long"> <br>
<img  id="5" src="../Projects/Images/Night/05.jpg" class="long"> <br>
<img  id="6" src="../Projects/Images/Night/06.jpg" class="long"> <br>
<img  id="7" src="../Projects/Images/Night/07.jpg" class="long"> <br>
<img  id="8" src="../Projects/Images/Night/08.jpg" class="long"> <br>
<img  id="9" src="../Projects/Images/Night/09.jpg" class="tall"> <br>
<img  id="10" src="../Projects/Images/Night/10.jpg" class="long"> <br>
<img  id="11" src="../Projects/Images/Night/11.jpg" class="long"> <br>
<img  id="12" src="../Projects/Images/Night/12.jpg" class="long"> <br>
<img  id="13" src="../Projects/Images/Night/13.jpg" class="long"> <br>
<img  id="14" src="../Projects/Images/Night/14.jpg" class="tall"> <br>
<img  id="15" src="../Projects/Images/Night/15.jpg" class="long"> <br>
<img  id="16" src="../Projects/Images/Night/16.jpg" class="tall"> <br>
<img  id="17" src="../Projects/Images/Night/17.jpg" class="long"> <br>
<img  id="18" src="../Projects/Images/Night/18.jpg" class="tall"> <br>
<img  id="19" src="../Projects/Images/Night/19.jpg" class="tall"> <br>
<img  id="20" src="../Projects/Images/Night/20.jpg" class="tall"> <br>
<img  id="21" src="../Projects/Images/Night/21.jpg" class="long"> <br>
<img  id="22" src="../Projects/Images/Night/22.jpg" class="long"> <br>
<img  id="23" src="../Projects/Images/Night/23.jpg" class="tall"> <br>
<img  id="24" src="../Projects/Images/Night/24.jpg" class="tall"> <br>
<img  id="25" src="../Projects/Images/Night/25.jpg" class="tall"> <br>
<img  id="26" src="../Projects/Images/Night/26.jpg" class="tall"> <br>
<img  id="27" src="../Projects/Images/Night/27.jpg" class="tall"> <br>
<img  id="28" src="../Projects/Images/Night/28.jpg" class="long"> <br>
<img  id="29" src="../Projects/Images/Night/29.jpg" class="tall"> <br>
<img  id="30" src="../Projects/Images/Night/30.jpg" class="long"> <br>
<img  id="31" src="../Projects/Images/Night/31.jpg" class="long"> <br>
</div>
</div>


</body>
<script>

    var id = 1;
    var container = $('#project-container');
    var scrollTo = $('#'+id);

    $('.next').click(function(){
    console.log(scrollTo);
    container.scrollTop(
    scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop()
     );
    id++;   
})


</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok first things first: if this is a raw copy of your code, your `<div id="project-container"` is unclosed (missing `>` at the end of it).
I tested it on my local host and closing the tag removes the error (you may use the W3 validator and copy-paste your HTML into it, to ensure it's valid: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input).

Comment: Make a JSfiddle

Answer (score 0):

IDs *cannot* be numeric. 1, 2, 3, ..., 9999 and so on are **not** valid `id` attributes.

Change your image `id`s from `1` to something like `image-1` and it should work.

Your JS will then look something like this:

```
    var id = 1;
    var container = $('#project-container');
    var scrollTo = $('#image-'+id);

    $('.next').click(function(){
    console.log(scrollTo);
    container.scrollTop(
    scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop()
     );
    id++;   
})
```

[HTML4 spec for reference:](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id)

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: HTML5 you can use ids that start with a number. You can have anything as the value of an id as long as it's unique and at least `1` in length.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you need to end this row `<div id="project-container">`.

I have created a small fiddle for your, without iteration and reference to IDs: https://jsfiddle.net/wk6bhejt/